# Maven leaves out a jar from WAR

Tags: maven, war

We use maven 2.2.1 to build project. A master pom lists modules that are built (some WAR project and some "plain" JARs).

Recently we added a new dependency into one of the WAR projects:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

When built locally from command line (*mvn clean package*) on a developers machine, it works fine. But when built on the automatic build system (by Hudson) the *httpcore* JAR (it is a dependency of *httpclient*) is not packaged into the final WAR. No error is reported, just the JAR is missing.

The maven *settings.xml* files are identical (except the repo path - the only noticeable non-default option is *offline=true*). What could be wrong?

Comment: That... sounds impossible... Could you run `mvn package` on the machine Hudson runs and see if the same effect occurs? If so, are `mvn dependency:tree` different somehow from the local?

Comment: I just run maven on the build system and the same effect occured: the httpcore jar is missing from the generated WARs. I did the build on a fresh checkout of the source files.

Comment: Please run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` on a machine with the problem and one without and check whether anything is different.

Comment: BTW: [Leave Maven 2...](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html)

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that comes to my mind is that your build machine has old version of one of your modules in m2 repo.
Clear up whole `$HOME/.m2/repository` (or where you keep the repo) and try again.

Comment: That is a good general advice, and would expose problems with modules not rebuilding when they should.

Answer (score 1):

Problem found. (and solved)

In short: the httpclient.jar in the repo was without its .pom file. (so maven did not know it had dependencies)

Long:

It is an offline repository, so missing artifacts must be fixed manually. The problem is I first copied the files to the wrong folder and maven did not "see" them. Then "blindly" followed its advice:

```
Missing:
----------
1) org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.6

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.apache.httpcomponents -DartifactId=
httpclient -Dversion=4.2.6 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
```

That would just copy the jar file to the repo, without the pom.

So I just copied the complete folder for *httpclient* into the repo (and its parent and some other related files that maven then complained about).

It's a form of user error, I guess.

Comment: Well, it copies the jar, but it _generates_ a POM for you (since you didn't specify one). The problem is that the generated POM doesn't specify any dependencies. There is a `-DpomFile` flag to that command that would have solved it for you.